# Immutable.js, how to quit search on first find

Tags: immutable.js

currently I am doing

```
var adnetCustomerModel = customersList.find((adnetCustomerModel) => {
            return adnetCustomerModel.getId() == customerId;
 })
```

but wasting CPU cycles as I have to continue and traverse the entire list (or so I am assuming that's what happens).

I'd like to quit on first find.
Now I know I can do a filter().first() (which I believe will have same waste of CPU cycles) but is there a better way?

If it was a normal `for` loop I would just break...
will the return achieve the same effect in immutable.js?

tx for reading,

Sean

Comment: The docs state it returns the first value found-what made you think it'd keep iterating after the first found valuer?

Comment: great I missed in the docs, tx for confirming...! +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immutable’s `find()` already returns only the first value for which the predicate returns true. It actually just wraps around the `findEntry()` method that’s implemented like this:

```
  findEntry(predicate, context, notSetValue) {
    var found = notSetValue;
    this.__iterate((v, k, c) => {
      if (predicate.call(context, v, k, c)) {
        found = [k, v];
        return false;
      }
    });
    return found;
  }
```

So, you’re not wasting any cycles. :)

Vanilla JavaScript `Array.prototype.find()` also returns the value of the first element to match the predicate.